# Is it permissible to hang out with my best friend and wife together

Tags: halal-haram

I am a male and have a male best friend. The question I have is: is it permissible to meet and hang out or For example, walk in the park with my wife and also my best friend? If you can answer my question and refer to Hadith or teaching that would be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is permissible for a wife to go anywhere she wants under the security of her husband. Though your friend is non-mahram to your wife. So you should keep your wife with you. Not close and alone with your friend. A non-mahram should not stay with a girl alone more than 10 minutes. So u should check these things. They can also talk with each other but unnecessary talk is not allowed. So you should spy these things that both don't talk to each other unnecessary or touch each other because this is considered as a sin. You can hangout with your wife and best friend anytime you want. Sorry! U couldn't find a hadith. But this is the answer in my knowledge.

Comment: Where do you get the 10 minutes time limit from?

Comment: 10 minutes? why not 11 minutes?